# Displaying open/closed sign

Tags: javascript

I want my site to display "Open" or "Closed" based on the current time.

My question is nothing is showing up on the site, so i'm trying to figure out whats wrong with the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var today = new Date(),
var open = "Open",
var closed = "Closed",
var display = document.getElementById('hours-display'); 
if (today.getHours() >= 9 && today.getHours() < 18) {
display.innerHTML = open;
} else {
display.innerHTML = closed;
}
</script>


<div id="hours-display"></div>
```

Comment: And your question is.....?

Comment: Seems like you've answered your own question.

Comment: Soooo shouldn't `var closed = "Open"` be `var closed = "Closed"` otherwise the output will be `Open` no matter if `open` or `closed` variable is used...

Comment: Are all users in the same time zone as the, um, "store"?

Comment: Start by looking at the errors thrown in browser console. The clues there would have given you a start

Answer (score 0):

You can only `getElementById` once the specified element has been declared. Additionally you used commas instead of semi-colons

```
<div id="hours-display"></div>
<script>
  var today = new Date();
  var display = document.getElementById("hours-display");
  if (today.getHours() >= 9 && today.getHours() < 18) {
    display.innerHTML = "Open";
  } else {
    display.innerHTML = "Closed";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Care to explain the changes or why this might be useful? Or do you expect people to just use it and not care to understand the changes?

Comment: It's for a client, Car dealership, they really wanted it

Answer (score 0):

The way you declare your variables are the issue. You should remove the var from the other variables since you are using commas like this:

```
var today = new Date(),
open = "Open",
closed = "Closed",
display = document.getElementById('hours-display'); 
if (today.getHours() >= 9 && today.getHours() < 18) {
    display.innerHTML = open;
} else {
    display.innerHTML = closed;
}
```

Comment: Did you try running it? Theres more that one error in the script

Comment: Well, i discovered the errors and updated my answer.

Comment: And the script tag needs to go below the DIV

Comment: @SamDenty Or the script needs to be placed in a DOM ready function like `window.onload=function(){}`